# Giving error of maximum recursion at some values

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a program to search a element recursively. Logic is simple
`return Search(array,start+1,end-1,element)`
explains how i am searching again and again. It is working fine for smaller values

**Example**
In the sorted array of `1000000` elements if i search `500` or less than `500` it works fine but if i search larger values like `5000` it gives error of `maximum recursion` has occurred. I don,t know where my logic is wrong.

```
1)start,end
2)start+1,end-1
Recurisive function
```

```
def Search(array,start,end,element):
    if end < start:
        return -1
    elif array[start] == element:
        return start
    elif array[end] == element:
        return end
    else:
        return Search(array,start+1,end-1,element)
```

Comment: If you're sure you want to use recursion and don't want to change the gist of your approach, you can use something like `sys.setrecursionlimit(len(array))` to avoid the error. This isn't the best approach but it would probably do the trick.

Comment: But why do you search on a **sorted** array in this way?

Comment: @ILS Just want to do some practice problems on recursion

Answer (score 2):

Your solution has linear complexity O(n). That is, it's not logically wrong, but you're using too much memory (to save the function state). because you're possibly calling your function n times. Instead, you should call it at most log(n) times, i.e. you can reach O(log(n)) complexity:

```
def search(arr, start, end, elem):
    if end < start:
        return -1
    middle = (start + end) // 2
    if arr[middle] == elem:
        return middle
    if arr[middle] > elem:
        return search(arr, start, middle - 1, elem)
    return search(arr, middle + 1, end, elem)
```

Comment: Bro I know i can do better than this but i need searching only using this logic

Comment: @lokp Can you use an iterative approach instead of using the recursive approach? It costs a lot to call a function n times. Your logic is correct. But this doesn't mean that your program will work :) You're using too much memory in this case

Comment: I know iterative method will be easy here but want to learn more about recursion

Comment: @lokp Calling a function is not "free". Under the hood, its state is somehow saved on the stack. If you call a function too many times (possibly 1000000 in this case), you're gonna run out of memory. So your approach is not wrong, but you don't have enough memory to run it. Instead, you should use a smarter approach. Instead of comparing `array[start]` and `array[end]` to `element`, you should compare `array[middle]` with `element`. in this case you need to call a function only log(1000000)=20 times instead of 1000000 ;) And this saves much much MUCH memory